# Nested loop involving date manipulation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, iteration, underscore.js

I'm working on a booking system whereas the price depends on seasons and those seasons are recurring yearly. So far everything works well except for the recurring seasons. I'm using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) with the [moment-range](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range) plugin, but that don't seem to cause the problems I'm facing. Because there was no other way to use moment-range with recurring ranges I thought to just iterate through my seasonsObject and create new seasons for the consecutive five (or whatever number) years. And that is basically, where I'm stuck: I can't get my loop to work as expected.

```
var seasonsObject = {
       low: {
          period: "low",
          seasonStart: "2017-11-01T12:01:00.000Z",
          seasonEnd: "2018-03-15T12:01:00.000Z"
       },
       high: {
         period: "high",
         seasonStart: "2018-06-01T12:01:00.000Z",
         seasonEnd: "2018-08-01T12:01:00.000Z"
       }
    }
var futureSeasons;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    futureSeasons = _.each(seasonsObject,(val) => { 
        val.range = moment.range(moment(val.seasonStart).add(i,'y'), moment(val.seasonEnd).add(i,'y')) 
    });
}
```

I tested the part which depends on moment.js and moment-range, so that I'm sure that my loop is not working properly – it seems to break after `i = 0` as I'm still only seeing the seasons of year one. I've also tried to use `_.map()` and `_.mapObject()` instead of `_.each()` but neither did the job.

However, my **desired** output would be:

```
futureSeasons: {
    low0: {
        period: "low",
        seasonStart: "2017-11-01T12:01:00.000Z",
        seasonEnd: "2018-03-15T12:01:00.000Z"
    },
    high0: {
        period: "high",
        seasonStart: "2018-06-01T12:01:00.000Z",
        seasonEnd: "2018-08-01T12:01:00.000Z"
    },
    low1: {
        period: "low",
        seasonStart: "2018-11-01T12:01:00.000Z",
        seasonEnd: "2018-03-15T12:01:00.000Z"
    },
    high1: {
        period: "high",
        seasonStart: "2019-06-01T12:01:00.000Z",
        seasonEnd: "2018-08-01T12:01:00.000Z"
    },
    low2: {
        period: "low",
        seasonStart: "2020-11-01T12:01:00.000Z",
        seasonEnd: "2018-03-15T12:01:00.000Z"
    },
    high2: {
        period: "high",
        seasonStart: "2021-06-01T12:01:00.000Z",
        seasonEnd: "2018-08-01T12:01:00.000Z"
    },
    ...
}
```

I'm using **Vue.js** and will try to wrap that behavior in a computed property! Any help highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```js
window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);

var seasonsObject = {
  low: {
    period: "low",
    seasonStart: "2017-11-01T12:01:00.000Z",
    seasonEnd: "2018-03-15T12:01:00.000Z"
  },
  high: {
    period: "high",
    seasonStart: "2018-06-01T12:01:00.000Z",
    seasonEnd: "2018-08-01T12:01:00.000Z"
  }
}


function makeFutureSeasons(count) {
  const futureSeasons = {};
  _.range(0, count).forEach(y => {
    Object.keys(seasonsObject).forEach(k => {
      const {
        period,
        seasonStart,
        seasonEnd
      } = seasonsObject[k];

      futureSeasons[k + y] = {
        period,
        seasonStart: moment(seasonStart).add(y, 'years').toISOString(),
        seasonEnd: moment(seasonEnd).add(y, 'years').toISOString()
      };
    });
  });
  return futureSeasons;
}

const fseasons = makeFutureSeasons(5);
console.log(fseasons);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-range/3.1.1/moment-range.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot! Well, I should have mention that I'm using vue.js but in essence this is what I'm trying to do, yes! I will give it a try in vue now.